# XDRP and Windows Remote Desktop Issues in Fedora 25

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, fedora

(Note: this used to work on Fedora 23)

My coworkers and I are attempting to use Windows Remote Desktop Connection to connect to machines running Fedora 25. We are running XRDP as our VNC provider, and using Windows 7.

Initially, when we attempt to connect from Windows, we get a black screen, then the connection drops.

I made the following change to the xrdp.ini file:

```
allow_channels=false
#allow_channels=true
```

This allows me to connect to the Fedora machine via Remote Desktop. Unfortunately, it only works once. On a second attempt, it fails. After the failure, running `ps -eaf | grep xrdp` shows TWO instances of `xrdp-sesman --nodaemon` running.

A second issue: once I log into the Fedora machine via remote desktop, I am unable to log into it locally due to an error message stating "could not acquire name on the session bus". I switched to a terminal, logged in as root, and ran `systemctl restart xrdp`, but was still unable to log in as my regaular user. (Note to self: disable root login once I fix this).

So two questions:

1. How can I fix the error where I can't log in more than once (I don't know which xrdp-sesman to kill, and I don't know if that will break xrdp).
2. How can I log in locally AND via remote desktop simultaneously?

Thanks for any help.

**update :** added error message text
Jason

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed the issue.

The trick was to make a few changes to /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini , create a .Xinitrc file to show what session manager to use, then create a XWrapper.config file.

Changes to xrdp.ini:

```
autorun=Xorg
max_bpp=16
```

.Xinitrc file:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ~/.xinitrc
#
# Executed by startx (run your window manager from here)

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ]; then
  for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/*; do
    [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
  done
  unset f
fi

# exec enlightenment_start
# exec i3
# exec mate-session
# exec xmonad
# exec startlxqt
# exec startlxde
# exec awesome
# exec bspwm
# exec gnome-session
# exec gnome-session --session=gnome-classic
# exec startkde
# exec startxfce4
# exec startfluxbox
# exec openbox-session
exec cinnamon-session
# exec pekwm
# exec catwm
# exec dwm
# exec startede
# exec icewm-session
# exec jwm
# exec monsterwm
# exec notion
# exec startdde       
# deepin-session
```

Finally, I created the Xwrapper.config file with a single line:

```
allowed_users=anybody
```

At this point, I could log in via the Windows Remote Desktop, as long as I changed the "session" dropdown from Xvnc to Xorg.